# What could be the reason sp.core.js is not loaded?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have this kind of weird problem in my SharePoint 2010 app. I edit a default form, I put a Content Editor Web Part and I add some javascript code to it. But I can't get a ClientContext, because the value of SP.ClientContext is undefined.

I checked where it's stored, but the sp.core.js file is mentioned in the head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.core.js?rev=7ByNlH%2BvcgRJg%2BRCctdC0w%3D%3D"></script>
```

When I put a "debugger" to stop the function and see the namespaces in Chrome's Dev Tools, I see that SP object has only SOD and UI.

What am I missing? Why isn't sp.core.js updating the SP object with it's functions? Do I need to add some functions that activate ClientContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for script files:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadContext, 'sp.js');
        function loadContext() {
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks :-) I need to learn more about it. Before I thought that jquery's document.ready is good enough. Could you suggest some resources about SharePoint's website life cycle?

Comment: There is a good article about SOD and script loading:http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2010/08/sharepoint-scripts-on-demand-spsod.html